# "Request is not available in this context" on Masterpage Page's design mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS.net 2010 ASP.net C# 4.0 and I've got many pages who use the same Masterpage. But for some reasons I didn't find for now, some pages never display in design mode of Visual Studio. Instead of seeing my designed page, I only see a Gray Square where we can read

**Error creating control - ContentPlaceHolder1**
Request is not available in this context.

Anyone know a reason and/or a way to resolve this?
Must tell that there's no errors in my whole solution and I can start debbuging normaly.

Note : I usualy talk french so feel free to tell me if there's something that wasn't clear!

Comment: Not sure but this post looks like the same issue you are facing. Take a look. Hope this helps.   http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/web/thread/7eb5b113-1b23-4b0e-8de3-b60daa632319

Comment: Rahul, write it as an answer. This make my solution working back!

Comment: what in particular on that page fixed your issue? Users might not want to traverse the page for answers since there isn't a marked answer on that page.

Comment: I want to let Rahul aswer to give him the "Accepted" answer! But in my case, this is the "Programmer35"'s answer on the page where he said to Remove a letter from the Inherits header, save, add it back and save it back. Then when you open your design mode, it works fine (for some time and you may have to do that many time). Thanks for precision Justin.

Comment: good to hear that it worked for you. I was thinking to post it as an answer but was not sure whether this is the exact issue you were facing and hence post it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but this post looks like the same issue you are facing. Take a look. Hope this helps.

[Check This](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/web/thread/7eb5b113-1b23-4b0e-8de3-b60daa632319)

Comment: In my case, this is the "Programmer35"'s answer where he saids to Remove a letter from the Inherits header, save, add it back and save it back. Then when you open your design mode and tadam! It works fine (for some time and you may have to do that many time)